# Obtaining a report derived from feature info in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm working with QGIS 3.16 Hannover and I've got a polygon layer that contains a UTM 10x10 km grid. I've created two relations (many to many) with two csv tables, that contain data on species presence (one for breeding and the other for wintering records) in each UTM cell. When using the `info` tool in QGIS, I retrieve both lists of species present in that particular cell.

[image]

Is it possible to get a, say, text file containing that information (the lists of species)? The more automatically, the better.

Comment: Are you looking for `"Layer" -> "Save As..." -> "MS Office Open XML spreadsheet [XLSX]"` (or other `CSV`, `ODS` format)?

Comment: No. Correct me if I'm mistaken, but when selecting a feature and saving it as..., as far as I know, it saves only the attributes of that feature, not including data from relations.

Answer (score 2):

A very similar case: square grid (Polish ATPOL) for vegetation analysis with only one field `Name`:

[image]

Let's add a `CSV` layer of observations which looks like:

[image]

And join it to `atpol_male` layer:

[image]

Finally, let's export `atpol_male` layer:

[image]

And check it's content:

[image]

Comment: But, doing what you propose, you'll get the whole set of information: all grid cells and their associate species information, don't you? What I need is only the information referring to the selected cell or cells.

Comment: Yes, you are right, @JesúsPinilla. Don't know other way. But you can always filter out required data outside qgis. And to be honest with you, for such spatial analysis I'm a big fan of R :)